# Unable to get user email with FacebookClient

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I am trying to login with Facebook using following code but unable to get users email address. I am missing something?

Here is request asp.net mvc action method which returns FacebookOAuthResult:

```
public ActionResult FacebookStartLogin(string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!this.Config.AuthenticationProviders.Facebook.IsDefined)
        {
            return ResultHelper.ForbiddenResult(this);
        }
        var oAuthClient = new FacebookOAuthClient();
        oAuthClient.AppId = this.Config.AuthenticationProviders.Facebook.ApiKey;
        oAuthClient.RedirectUri = new Uri(Request.Url, Url.Action("FacebookFinishLogin", "Authentication"));
        var loginUri = oAuthClient.GetLoginUrl(new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "state", Session.SessionToken } });

        Session.NextUrl = returnUrl;

        return new RedirectResult(loginUri.AbsoluteUri);
    }
```

and following action method tries to retrieve user details but fails to get user email address

```
public ActionResult FacebookFinishLogin(string code, string state)
    {
        if (!this.Config.AuthenticationProviders.Facebook.IsDefined)
        {
            return ResultHelper.ForbiddenResult(this);
        }
        FacebookOAuthResult oauthResult;
        if (state == Session.SessionToken && FacebookOAuthResult.TryParse(Request.Url, out oauthResult))
        {
            if (oauthResult.IsSuccess)
            {
                FacebookClient fbClient = new FacebookClient();
                dynamic result = fbClient.Post("oauth/access_token", new
                {
                    client_id = this.Config.AuthenticationProviders.Facebook.ApiKey,
                    client_secret = this.Config.AuthenticationProviders.Facebook.SecretKey,
                    redirect_uri = new Uri(Request.Url, Url.Action("FacebookFinishLogin", "Authentication")),
                    code = code
                });

                fbClient.AccessToken = result.access_token;

                dynamic facebookUser = fbClient.Get("me?fields=id,name,first_name,last_name,about,link,birthday,timezone,email");

                User user = _service.GetByProviderId(AuthenticationProvider.Facebook, facebookUser.id);
                if (user == null)
                {
                    //Its a new user for the application
                    user = SecurityHelper.CreateUser(facebookUser);
                    user = _service.Add(user, AuthenticationProvider.Facebook, facebookUser.id);
                }

                //Log the user in
                Session.User = new UserState(user, AuthenticationProvider.Facebook);

                if (!User.MobileNoVerified)
                    return Redirect(Url.Action("VerifyMobile", "Users"));

                return Redirect(Session.NextUrl);
            }
            return ResultHelper.ForbiddenResult(this);
        }
        else
            return ResultHelper.ForbiddenResult(this);
    }
```

In response we can see other parameters shared by FB but not email. Here is debug output image:
[Debug output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DINgq.png)

Comment: You should be more clear on what API and language you are using. Also, there is no way to diagnose without errors. If you want others to figure this out you need to give them resources. Correct indentation is also considered standard.

Comment: Hi Jstaff.. I am using c# with Facebook API 2.4. also attached the debug response image.

Comment: Awesome looks better

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be correct. Make sure you are requesting the proper permissions from facebook http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/

Examples: https://gist.github.com/ntotten/4341111

Comment: Thanks buddy.. but I am not able to find page on Facebook developer portal where I can set the proper permissions from Facebook. above link provides the what all details can be requested from user but how to set them for a app.

Comment: Take a look at this example: https://gist.github.com/ntotten/4341111#file-accountcontroller2-cs

Notice the addition of the `scope = "email"`

Comment: Your code is in place to "get" the information, but the facebook user has to grant you permission first.

Comment: added scope with email as it's value but still email not returened by Fabcebook:  dynamic result = fbClient.Post("oauth/access_token", new
                    {
                        client_id = this.Config.AuthenticationProviders.Facebook.ApiKey,
                        client_secret = this.Config.AuthenticationProviders.Facebook.SecretKey,
                        redirect_uri = new Uri(Request.Url, Url.Action("FacebookFinishLogin", "Authentication")),
                        code = code,
                        scope = "email"
                    });

Comment: Once we are redirected to Facebook login page with URL generated by "FacebookStartLogin" action method(as mentioned above), the Facebook login page not even asking for any permissions. It's just asking for user name and password and redirecting to "FacebookFinishLogin" action method on successful login.. Is there anything missing as Facebook is not showing permissions on login page.

Comment: It's ignoring the scope. You can try to remove your app permissions in facebook manually, and authenticate again. Please update your latest code with the scope included.

Comment: Still email is not being returned.. I tried removing app permissions and it did ask for permission next time I tried login with Facebook but it asked permissions only for public profile... here are my code modifications to include scope....

Comment: dynamic result = fbClient.Post("oauth/access_token", new
                    {
                        client_id = this.Config.AuthenticationProviders.Facebook.ApiKey,
                        client_secret = this.Config.AuthenticationProviders.Facebook.SecretKey,
                        redirect_uri = new Uri(Request.Url, Url.Action("FacebookFinishLogin", "Authentication")),
                        code = code,
                        scope = "email"
                    });

Comment: and this how I am trying to access them: fbClient.AccessToken = result.access_token;
                    dynamic facebookUser = fbClient.Get("me?fields=id,name,first_name,last_name,about,link,birthday,timezone,email");